# Dictionary of dictionaries vs dictionary of class instances

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I understand what a class is, a bundle of attributes and methods stored together in one object. However, i don't think i have ever really grasped their full power. I taught myself to manipulate large volumes of data by using 'dictionary of dictionary' data structures. I'm now thinking if i want to fit in with the rest of the world then i need to implement classes in my code, but i just don't get how to make the transition.

I have a script which gets information about sales orders from a SQL query, performs operations on the data, and outputs it to a csv.

1) (the way i currently do it, store all the orders in a dictionary of dictionaries)

```
cursor.execute(querystring)

# create empty dictionary to hold orders
orders = {}

# define list of columns returned by query
columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]

for row in cursor:
    # create dictionary of dictionaries where key is order_id
    # this allows easy access of attributes given the order_id
    orders[row.order_id] = {}
    for i, v in enumerate(columns):
        # add each field to each order
        orders[row.order_id][v] = row[i]

# example operation
for order, fields in orders.iteritems():
    fields['long'], fields['lat'] = getLongLat(fields['post_code'])

# example of another operation
cancelled_orders = getCancelledOrders()
for order_id in cancelled_orders:
    orders[order_id]['status'] = 'cancelled'

# Other similar operations go here...

# write to file here...
```

2) (the way i THINK i would do it if i was using classes)

```
class salesOrder():


    def __init__(self, cursor_row):
        for i, v in enumerate(columns):
            setattr(self, v, cursor_row[i])


    def getLongLat(self, long_lat_dict):
        self.long, self.lat = long_lat_dict[self.post_code]['long'], long_lat_dict[self.post_code]['lat']


    def cancelOrder(self):
        self.status = 'cancelled'


    # more methods here


cursor.execute(querystring)

# create empty dictionary to hold orders
orders = {}

# define list of columns returned by query
columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]

for row in cursor:
    orders[row.order_id] = salesOrder(row)
    orders[row.order_id].getLongLat()

# example of another operation
cancelled_orders = getCancelledOrders()
for order_id in cancelled_orders:
    orders[order_id].cancelOrder()

# other similar operations go here

# write to file here
```

I just get the impression that i'm not quite understanding the best way to use classes. Have i got the complete wrong idea about how to use classes? Is there some sense to what i'm doing but it needs refactoring? or am i trying to use classes for the wrong purpose?

Comment: Think of a class as nothing more than a dictionary with custom methods.

Comment: (a) It seems your `row` is a class object the way you present it in the first example (e.g. `row.order_id`). (b) `row.column` will not work. (c) Let's back up a little bit, I think the reason you put your data into a dictionary is to look it up easily, then update. However, that's what your database is for, why not query the database and update directly?

Comment: @HaiVu (a) the row is a class object, but it's just a row returned by the cursor, i understand how to use existing classes (mostly), i'm more concerned about the best way to implement my own classes (b) good spot on row.column, my bad, this is why i have used enumerate(columns) in the second example to get around this, i'll edit the question now (c) That would be a better approach in the given situation but i have simplified by problem for the purposes of the question and a pure db solution is not necessarily appropriate for my wider project (hope that makes sense)

Comment: Well, part of it is that you could put your dbcol-attrib mapping in say method *dbset* in class DBInst.  Then SalesOrder can be an subclass of that and call dbsetb from init.  Presto, db-aware classes throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to guess what you are trying to do since I have no idea what your "row" looks like. I assume you have the variable `columns` which is a list of column names. If that is the case, please consider this code snippet:

```
class SalesOrder(object):
    def __init__(self, columns, row):
        """ Transfer all the columns from row to this object """
        for name in columns:
            value = getattr(row, name)
            setattr(self, name, value)
        self.long, self.lat = getLongLat(self.post_code)

    def cancel(self):
        self.status = 'cancelled'

    def as_row(self):
        return [getattr(self, name) for name in columns]

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.as_row())

# Create the dictionary of class
orders = {row.order_id: SalesOrder(columns, row) for row in cursor}

# Cancel
cancelled_orders = getCancelledOrders()
for order_id in cancelled_orders:
    orders[order_id].cancel()

# Print all sales orders
for sales_order in orders.itervalues():
    print(sales_order)
```

At the lowest level, we need to be able to create a new `SalesOrder` object from the `row` object by copying all the attributes listed in `columns` over. When initializing a `SalesOrder` object, we also calculate the longitude and latitude as well.

With that, the task of creating the dictionary of class objects become easier:

```
orders = {row.order_id: SalesOrder(columns, row) for row in cursor}
```

Our `orders` is a dictionary with `order_id` as keys and `SalesOrder` as values. Finally, the task up cancelling the orders is the same as your code.

In addition to what you have, I created a method called `as_row()` which is handy if later you wish to write a `SalesOrder` object into a CSV or database. For now, I use it to display the "raw" row. Normally, the `print` statement/function will invoke the `__str__()` method to get a string presentation for an object, if not found, it will attempt to invoke the `__repr__()` method, which is what we have here.

Comment: Hi, this is very helpful. It gives me some ideas about how to better structure my code, it also assures me that the way i am trying to use multiple instances of the same class is a 'valid' use of classes. BTW the 'columns' variable is just a list of the fields i have selected in my sql query

Comment: If you want to retain the ability to reference nested items by sequential brackets, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014621/a-python-class-that-acts-like-dict

Answer (score 2):

Classes are mostly useful for coupling data to behaviour, and for providing structure (naming and documenting the association of certain properties, for example).

You're not doing either of those here - there's no real behaviour in your class (it doesn't *do* anything to the data), and all the structure is provided externally. The class instances are just used for their attribute dictionaries, so they're just a fancy wrapper around your old dictionary.

If you *do* add some real behaviour (above `getLongLat` and `cancelOrder`), or some real structure (other than a list of arbitrary column names and field values passed in from outside), then it makes sense to use a class.