# What is it called when using [ ] to set object variables?

Tags: python

If I had a `dict` object say `values = {'a': 'alpha', 'b': 'bravo'}`.

I've seen use cases where one may do `values['a']` to get the value of the `a` key.

Now I am aware this is a normal way to access `dict` values, but I have also seen it used with objects such as a `Tk.Scrollbar['command'] = yadayada`.

Is there a name or documentation for this practice of using `[ ]` with objects?

Comment: Are you sure `Tk.Scrollbar` isn't just a dictionary?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014621/a-python-class-that-acts-like-dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[ ]` is called indexing or slicing (or sometimes array/sequence/mapping-like access). The `x[idx] = val` is called index or slice *assigment*.

The methods that are responsible how the instance acts when indexed or sliced are:

- [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__),
- [`__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) and
- [`__delitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__).
- (In Python-2.x there is also `__getslice__`, ... but these are deprecated since python 2.0 - if you don't inherit from a class that uses these you shouldn't need those)

For example (missing any actual implementation, just some `print`s):

```
class Something(object):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print('in getitem')
    def __setitem__(self, item, newvalue):
        print('in setitem')
    def __delitem__(self, item):
        print('in delitem')
```

For example:

```
>>> sth = Something()
>>> sth[10]  
in getitem
>>> sth[10] = 100  
in setitem
>>> del sth[10]  
in delitem
```

Comment: `__getslice__` has been deprecated since Python *2.0*, but it was still used by built-in types, so one needs to override it when subclassing those.

Comment: @chepner That's correct. I just wanted to mention `__getslice__` without going into details - so I haven't double checked what I've written there. I updated the answer.

Comment: It's not called "slicing"  unless the slice syntax is used (i.e. there is at least one `:` in the `[]`).

Answer (score 0):

This is briefly described in the python tkinter documentation. Tkinter does it simply as a convenience, the feature has no name that is specific to tkinter.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tkinter.html#setting-options

> Options control things like the color and border width of a widget. Options can be set in three ways:
>
> At object creation time, using keyword arguments
>
> `fred = Button(self, fg="red", bg="blue")`
>
> After object creation, treating the option name like a dictionary index
>
> `fred["fg"] = "red"`
>   `fred["bg"] = "blue"`
>
> Use the config() method to update multiple attrs subsequent to object creation
>
> `fred.config(fg="red", bg="blue")`

For more general purpose information outside of the context of tkinter, see [A python class that acts like dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014621/a-python-class-that-acts-like-dict)