# Calling python method

Tags: python

I am newbie to python object oriented programming. I am trying to understand **binary tree** implantation code using python.

My understanding is **object.method** is the way to call the function. But here the object is called as `object[key]="value"` without explicitly calling the function like `object.put("key","value)` . Please help me to understand this code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A python class that acts like dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014621/a-python-class-that-acts-like-dict)

Comment: Any class that implements the special `__setitem__` method also supports the `object[key] = value` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like many languages that support object-oriented programming, Python has operators that can be overloaded by different classes as appropriate.

For example, when you write `x + y`, that calls `x.__add__(y)` (slightly oversimplified, but not in ways that are relevant here).

The `[]` here is just another operator. When you write `object[key]="value"`, that calls `object.__setitem__(key, "value")`.

So, you are doing object-oriented method calling, just with a little bit of syntactic sugar on top to make it more readable.